How to run a YML file in GitLab CI/CD with JMX and CSV files?
I’m trying to set up a GitLab CI/CD pipeline that runs a JMeter performance test using a .jmx file and a .csv file. I have a JMX file (GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx) and a CSV file (Config_Setup_LotInfo_sample.csv) that I want to use in the pipeline.
So far, I have been able to create a basic .gitlab-ci.yml file, but I’m unsure how to correctly configure it to run the JMeter tests with these files. Could anyone help me with the correct syntax or steps to configure the GitLab CI/CD pipeline for this scenario?
Here's what I’ve tried so far in my .gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:

jmeter
report
variables:

Compression and general settings
FF_USE_FASTZIP: "true" ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fastest" CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fastest"

Project and environment settings
ENV: "prd" PROJECT: "nvis" TARGET: "jmeter"

JMeter test files
JMX_FILE: "GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx" CSV_FILE_PATH: "results.csv" JMX_WRITE: "result_output"

jmeter-build: stage: jmeter image: registry.example.com/jmeter_base:1.0.3 before_script: # Copy JMX file to JMeter directory - cp JMeter-sample/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3 - mkdir -p "$BUILD_PATH" script: # Execute JMeter test - sh jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" -n -t /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx -l /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.csv -e -o /GIS_2CSV_sample_sya - cp /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.csv /builds/example/devops/jmeter/report && cp -r /GIS_2CSV_sample_sya /builds/example/devops/jmeter/report

report_job: stage: report image: alpine:3.8 dependencies: - jmeter-build

I'm facing issues with properly linking the JMX and CSV files, and I want to ensure the pipeline successfully runs the test and generates the report. Here’s what I’ve tried, but I’m not sure if the file paths and syntax are correct.
Could anyone help me identify any issues in the .gitlab-ci.yml file, especially with how to run the JMeter test using the .jmx file with the .csv file in the GitLab CI/CD pipeline?

There are two GitLab CI/CD snap packages in Ubuntu. Are you using either of them and if so which one are you using?

You posted this here too... https://stackoverflow.com/q/79271154/
